# Call an axis2 web service from a java application

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have create one simple web service and I deploy it to the axis2 web application based on [this tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/69/websvc/gs-axis.html)

After creating my service, I am able to deploy it to the server and I can see the WSDL file by this `url: localhost:8084/axis2/services/HelloAxisWorld?wsdl`

Now, I want to call this service by an independent java application. I found some pieces of code that makes the invocation, but I am facing problems because I suppose that I don't include the proper libraries in my project.

Does anybody knows an example to call the web service by using axis2?

Comment: Can you check out the example [here](http://roseindia.net/webservices/axis2/axis2-client.shtml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple Google for 'axis2 client tutorial' gives me [this](http://roseindia.net/webservices/axis2/axis2-client.shtml). It covers setting up your classpath properly, generating java from the WSDL via `wsdl2java`, and developing the client from this.

Comment: You are right. I followed the tutorial and I created the client. Thank you.